# How to change background Color on external element drop based on it's id: Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to change background Color of the external element on drop. So how to do that?

My code is following and I wanted to do something like if I drop red then red color of element on drop. If I drop green then...... so basically, based on it's id it change the color of element. As if you see then when you drop anything on week calendar, it's by default color is getting blue but it should transform to red as you are dropping red for ex.

Any help will be really useful thanks guys

Here is my code:

```
jsFiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/jimil/8hqe3wxd/2/
```

Comment: are you wondering what the code is to change the background color on drop, or what the 'drop' event is that you need to listen to?

Comment: yes, as I have no idea how to do that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to add a `data-attribute` to the draggable components, not rely on their class (since theres more in their class than just the color)

and then when building the little dragged components in the `external events` section, set a color attribute (either `red`, `orange`, `purple` or the actual css color)

http://jsfiddle.net/8hqe3wxd/4/

in the fiddle, observe i added data attributes to the html:

```
<div class='fc-event orange' id="1" data-color="orange">Orange</div>
<div class='fc-event red' id="2" data-color="red">Red</div>
<div class='fc-event purple' id="3" data-color="purple">Purple</div>
```

and added a line to the external events config

```
color: $(this).data('color')
```

this is storing what color you want each draggable to be, and setting that color when building the little calendar element.
hopefully this is what you want

Comment: drop: function(date) {
    
    //Call when you drop any red/green/blue class to the week table.....first time runs only.....
    console.log("dropped");
    console.log(date.format());
    console.log(this.id);
    if(this.id == 1) {
     color: $(this).data('color')
    }

Comment: am I write or wrong sorry not so good with it can you able to guide me in my mention fiddle please

Comment: Hi Thank you so much really thanks:) you seems expert I post one more question related to it so will you able to help me in that as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746441/how-to-get-end-time-on-drop-and-eventdrop-with-external-elements-in-fullcalendar